Isekai manga where the mc has a writing skill
I'm looking for an isekai manga where the Main Character (MC) has some type or writing skill (kanji I think or the other Japanese writing) I don't remember if he was transportated with other people but I think so.
I read this like two or three years ago and I read it on an Spanish website to read manga. I think the MC has medium-length black hair and later he was traveling with a pretty girl, I think he was the nonchalant gloomy type

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

It was like two or three years ago and I read it on an Spanish website to read manga, visortmo .com. I think the mc has medium-lenght black hair and later he was traveling with a pretty girl, I think he was the nonchalant gloomy type

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

For example, what did his writing skill allow him to do? Was he heroic or just trying to live a quiet life? Did the manga contain explicit sex/violence/gore/nudity? Did he woo the pretty girl? Did she have any powers? What was her name? Was the setting fantastical or medieval or futuristic? How did he get transported? Who gave him the writing power?

Thank you, I find it, the next time I'd try to be more specific

This is likely Konjiki no Word Master: Yuusha Yonin ni Makikomareta Unique Cheat.

There has been much conflict between the races of the Humas, the Gabranth, and the Evila. To combat the Demon King race Evila, the kingdom summons five high school students from 21st century Japan who have the power of Heroes. However, only four out of five of those students had the status title of 'Hero'. Okamura Hiiro was summoned by accident since he sat near the other four students in class. Unlike them, he did not have the title of a 'Hero' but instead he had the title of 'Word Master' and 'Innocent Bystander'.

The protagonist is summoned to another world along with 4 of his classmates. These classmates are proclaimed as heroes, while he appears to be an "Innocent Bystander" according to his status screen. He also gets the power of "Word Master", but does not mention this.
He meets an old fortune teller that tells him more details of his power, and he tests it on a rock by drawing a kanji in the air.
 
Immediately after this he repairs the rock by writing the kanji for "Origin", returning it to its previous state.

Yes, yes. Very good. Have an upvote.

Now make yourself useful and go and answer all of these; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isekai?tab=Unanswered

It is, thank you so much! I was going crazy trying to find it, thank you. ♡
